# PHP: Get timezone identifier offset from UTC

Tags: php

I know `\DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` returns all timezone identifiers, but how can I retrieve their actual offset from UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is method [getoffset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php)

```
<?php
// Create two timezone objects, one for Taipei (Taiwan) and one for
// Tokyo (Japan)
$dateTimeZoneTaipei = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Taipei");
$dateTimeZoneJapan = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");

// Create two DateTime objects that will contain the same Unix timestamp, but
// have different timezones attached to them.
$dateTimeTaipei = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneTaipei);
$dateTimeJapan = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneJapan);

// Calculate the GMT offset for the date/time contained in the $dateTimeTaipei
// object, but using the timezone rules as defined for Tokyo
// ($dateTimeZoneJapan).
$timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneJapan->getOffset($dateTimeTaipei);

// Should show int(32400) (for dates after Sat Sep 8 01:00:00 1951 JST).
var_dump($timeOffset);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an associative array mapping timezones and their offset using the `getOffset` method of `DateTime` instance.

`getOffset` returns the *difference in seconds* of a date evaluated in the time zone of the provided datetime argument (in our example, this is the current time in utc), and the same datetime as evaluated in the local time zone.

```php
$utcNow = new DateTime('now', (new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
$identOffset = array_map(
    function ($ident) use ($utcNow) {
        $localTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($ident);
        $offset = $localTimeZone->getOffset($utcNow);
        return [$ident => $offset] ;
    },
    DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()
);
$identOffset = array_merge(...$identOffset);
var_dump($identOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://carbon.nesbot.com/

```
// You will get timezone offset as string
Carbon::now('Asia/Kathmandu')->getOffsetString(); // +05:45
```